# missing gd.h header error while building iso via LFS 7.5

Tags: linux, gcc, g++, header-files, linux-from-scratch

I am trying to build centos6 based iso via LFS 7.5 technique.
While preparing glibc for compilation (page 38) i am getting error( log at link)
"fatal error: gd.h no such file ..." , though the header file is present in my /usr/include.
any solution/ fix ?

http://www.4shared.com/file/TbVJ0AuLce/config.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the fix,
i had to change the location of default dynamic linker of gcc to use the one installed in
/tools.
The following step on page 34 was skipped:

```
for file in $(find gcc/config -name linux64.h -o -name linux.h -o -name sysv4.h)
do
cp -uv $file{,.orig}
sed -e 's@/lib\(64\)\?\(32\)\?/ld@/tools&@g' \
-e 's@/usr@/tools@g' $file.orig > $file
echo '
#undef STANDARD_STARTFILE_PREFIX_1
#undef STANDARD_STARTFILE_PREFIX_2
#define STANDARD_STARTFILE_PREFIX_1 "/tools/lib/"
#define STANDARD_STARTFILE_PREFIX_2 "" ' >> $file
touch $file.orig
done
```